# How to add custom Animated icon to the joomla menu ? like the one shown below without the title?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I want to add custom animation to the joomla menu instead of title. How to do that?
I want to add the animation style menu shown in hte link
https://sarasoueidan.com/demos/navicon-transformicons/

Comment: on top of the linked page there is a tutorial - have you read it?

Comment: Yeah but I don't where add those code in Joomla

Comment: As @FFrewin stated, this page gives all the info on how to implement it: https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/navicon-transformicons/ If you are, also, asking the question of *where* to implement it, then it's going to depend on a lot of variables. I'm going to venture to say that you will likely be better off using a menu extension that has this feature. Otherwise, you are going to need to build your own (or highly customize the default Joomla! menu extension with overrides).